# How to append substring into main string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

**My original string is :** 
**Låt** den jäsa tifgdfgfll dubbel storlek ungdfgdfder en handduk **endtimer** dfgsdg fgsdfg hello ho  hi **Låt** den jäsa till dubbel storlek undegdfgr en handduk **endtimer** heouu hiy hinl  **Låt** den jäsa till dubbel stofgdfgrlek under en hfdgdfndduk **endtimer** jijfr ii iuwii  **Låt** den jäsa till dugdfgbbel storgdfglek under en handdgdfguk **endtimer** dfdf **Låt** den jäsa tfdgfdill dubbel storgdfglek under en handduk **endtimer**

And i want to add "**iOS**" before "**Låt**" and add "**objective c**" after "**endtimer**" in original string.

**So i want this output string :**
**iOS** Låt den jäsa tifgdfgfll dubbel storlek ungdfgdfder en handduk endtimer **objective c** dfgsdg fgsdfg hello ho  hi **iOS** Låt den jäsa till dubbel storlek undegdfgr en handduk endtimer **objective c** heouu hiy hinl  **iOS** Låt den jäsa till dubbel stofgdfgrlek under en hfdgdfndduk endtimer **objective c** jijfr ii iuwii  **iOS** Låt den jäsa till dugdfgbbel storgdfglek under en handdgdfguk endtimer **objective c** dfdf **iOS** Låt den jäsa tfdgfdill dubbel storgdfglek under en handduk ca endtimer **objective c**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this

```
NSString *appendString = [yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Låt" withString:@"iOS Låt"];
appendString = [appendString     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"endtimer" withString:@"endtimer objective c"];
```

Answer (score 2):

An option:

```
NSString *string = @"Låt den jäsa tifgdfgfll dubbel storlek ungdfgdfder en handduk endtimer dfgsdg fgsdfg hello ho hi Låt den jäsa till dubbel storlek undegdfgr en handduk endtimer heouu hiy hinl Låt den jäsa till dubbel stofgdfgrlek under en hfdgdfndduk endtimer jijfr ii iuwii Låt den jäsa till dugdfgbbel storgdfglek under en handdgdfguk endtimer dfdf Låt den jäsa tfdgfdill dubbel storgdfglek under en handduk endtimer";

NSString *mainString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", @"iOS", string, @"objective c"];
```

OR

```
NSString *string = @"Låt den jäsa tifgdfgfll dubbel storlek ungdfgdfder en handduk endtimer dfgsdg fgsdfg hello ho hi Låt den jäsa till dubbel storlek undegdfgr en handduk endtimer heouu hiy hinl Låt den jäsa till dubbel stofgdfgrlek under en hfdgdfndduk endtimer jijfr ii iuwii Låt den jäsa till dugdfgbbel storgdfglek under en handdgdfguk endtimer dfdf Låt den jäsa tfdgfdill dubbel storgdfglek under en handduk endtimer";

NSString *mainString = @"iOS ";

mainString = [mainString stringByAppendingString:string];

mainString = [mainString stringByAppendingString:@" objective c"];
```

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I want to append string before "Låt" and after "endtimer"in entire Main string not only from starting.

Comment: So the end result of both is same as you required